# try and catch in stream java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, try-catch

I'm trying to use map on stream and using try/catch on the map function but I get an error:

> missing return statement

```
public Stream<Integer> scale(List<Integer> values, Integer factor) {
    return values.stream()
            .map( n -> {
                try {
                    return n / factor;
                } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: You will have to return a `Integer`in the `catch` block or after the try/catch. This could be `null`.

Comment: Well, when `ArithmeticException` will be thrown what value should be returned? Are you returning it? Where?

Comment: Or just get rid of the try/catch.

Comment: What does the consumer of the `Stream<Integer>` expect? Will he be able to handle `null` values? How about changing the result type to `Stream<Optional<Integer>>`?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to return an `Integer` from `map`. The value can be `null` if this makes sense for your use case. If the consumer of the `Stream<Integer>` is able to handle `null` values, you can do this.

```java
.map( n -> {
  try {
    return n / factor;
  } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null; // <-- return here
  }
});
```

Note that returing `null` is only one of many options. It all depends on what you want to do with the resulting `Stream<Integer>`. Only you can tell us.

Comment: I do not think returning null is a good idea, maybe instead return `Optional` in both cases?

Comment: I don't recommend using `null`s in streams. I'd prefer to at least return `Optional<Integer>` instead, or just do a `factor != 0` before using this code in map and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead.

Comment: You are both correct. But since we don't known how the resulting stream is used, let's keep things simple.

Comment: Those options are simple and cleaner than current OPs code. Or would you code like this in your own solutions?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Of course not. But is it to us to change the signature of `scale`? The OP will have to tell us if he is OK with `Optional<Integer>` or throwing an exception on the first error. We should not guess how the message is supposed to behave.

Comment: You could just include all those possible solutions in your answer with their pros and cons - I guess that it is the purpose of SO - to teach.

Comment: Nope, no teaching here :) But please go ahead and edit my answer. I will gladly turn it into a community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same error as if you had a function as follows:

```
public int foo() {
    if (bar()) return 1;
}
```

If `bar()` returns false, this function does not return anything, which the compiler is not happy with. You **must** return something. Your options are:

- an obvious integer value representing faliure, e.g. -1, 0, defined in a `static final int` most likely
- `null`, although this can lead to `NullPointerException`s later in the stream, so worth avoiding
- `Optional<Integer>` although this requires changing the later operations in the stream to check `Optional.isPresent()`

On a side note, RxJava has nice functionality for handling this sort of thing in an elegant way.

Comment: How is your answer related to streams and especially `map`?

Comment: This is not specifically related to streams, but is related to the "missing return statment error". This error confused me when I first encountered it, as I was not aware that statement lambdas needed a return statement, whereas expression lambdas didn't.